# Java emits event to be cached in JavaScript - Nashorn

Tags: javascript, java, events, nashorn

I need to emit some string constant event in Java which I will be able to catch in JavaScript using Nashorn. The idea I came up with is as follows:

Java:

```
Event event = Event.create();
//when something happens
event.emit("type1");
```

JavaScript:

```
var Event = Java.type('mypackage.Event'); //Some Java event class
var event = Event.create();
event.watch(eventHandler);

function eventHandler(event) {
    switch(event.type) {
        case 'type1':
            if(this.ontype1) this.ontype1();
            break;
        case 'type2':
            if(this.ontype2) this.ontype2();
            break;
        //...
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to emit this constants `type1`, `type2` etc. How to write this `emit` function. Any ideas?